# An open set is always union of $B(\varepsilon)$'s

Tags: general-topology

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open set. Prove/disprove that there exist $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$U=\bigcup_{i} B(x_i, \varepsilon)$$ where $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $B(x, \varepsilon)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}: |x-y|<\varepsilon\}$.

If the statement is false, is it true something "similar"?

Comment: Any constraints on the index set?

Comment: Consider $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(n, n+\dfrac1n\right).$

Comment: Does $\varepsilon$ depend on $x$ or is given?

Comment: @lhf: depend on $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general theorem of the structure of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, that can be seen [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Open_Sets_in_Real_Number_Line). As every open set can be writen (uniquely) as a disjoint enumerable union of intervals $U=\bigcup_{i}I_i$, where $I_i=(a_i,b_i)$, we have as a corolary your question. Just take $x_i=\frac{a_i+b_i}{2}$, and $\varepsilon_i=\frac{b_i-a_i}{2}$.